# Is there a term for a disease that is spread ONLY from person to person?

Tags: terminology, science, medical

I'm looking for a term to describe a disease that is spread ONLY from person to person, not from animal to person (**zoonosis**):

> **Zoonosis**: any disease of animals communicable to humans ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/zoonosis?s=t))

My first thought was **infectious disease**, but this has too broad a definition; it encompasses both zoonotic diseases and (for lack of a better term) non-zoonotic diseases:

> **Infectious disease**: a disease resulting from the presence and activity of a pathogenic microbial agent. ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/infectious-disease?s=t))

**Communicable disease** likewise refers to *any* disease spread to humans, whether it is spread by another human or by an animal:

> **Communicable disease**: a disease that is transmitted through direct contact with an infected individual or indirectly through a vector. Also called **contagious disease**. ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/communicable-disease?s=t))

Is there any term (preferably a scientific/medical term, but a layman's term would suffice) for a disease which is spread ONLY from person to person, and not from animal to person? I would like to use a term that describes what such a disease *is*, rather than skirting the issue by describing what it *is not* (e.g., non-zoonotic disease or non-vector-borne disease).

Comment: Kace36 has the right term, but I've read more than my share of textbooks and papers on communicable diseases and *never* seen that word used (to within rounding error). (Zoonotic appears, but not anthroponotic.) They would just describe it as a disease that is communicated person-to-person (or spread by "person-to-person contact"). It sounds less fancy, I guess, but it's substantially more clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**These diseases are known as [anthroponoses](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/9/3/02-0208_article)** (adjective form: **anthroponotic**)

> Anthroponoses (Greek “anthrópos” = man, “nosos” = disease) are
>   diseases transmissible from human to human. Examples include rubella,
>   smallpox, diphtheria, gonorrhea, ringworm (Trichophyton rubrum), and
>   trichomoniasis.

NVZ also provided this [link to anthroponoses](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Anthroponotic_disease) in my comments section.

---

**Issues from Comments Section below (addressed)**

1. Janus mentioned this might not be *exactly* correct in the comments. I want to explain why this *is* definitely the correct word even if we are being meticulous about what the OP meant exactly. And there is no offense to Janus. None at all. I just want to clear it up.

Zoonoses [that were transmissible to humans] were originally called anthropozoonoses, and the reverse were called, zooanthroponoses [diseases from humans to animals]. There was a consensus that this caused confusion because scientists were mixing the 2 varieties and so they came up with the usage of the word: [anthroponoses - link to Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ONO42zYIEn0C&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q&f=false)

In addition, this [CDC Appendix of disease types](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/9/3/02-0208-techapp1.pdf) clearly lists the category: **Anthroponoses** (of which each one is a human to human *only* vector). In fact they specifically mention on that page, for those diseases which could cause confusion, that it is of the *human genotype* only variety. An example: [Giardiasis](http://www.cfsph.iastate.edu/FastFacts/pdfs/giardiasis_F.pdf); because it can affect both humans and animals but there is a human genotype that is only transmitted from human to human and this would known as an **anthronponotic** disease of Giardiasis.

**Sources:**

CDC: [Hubálek Z. Emerging Human Infectious Diseases: Anthroponoses, Zoonoses, and Sapronoses. Emerging Infectious Diseases. 2003;9(3):403-404. doi:10.3201/eid0903.020208.](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/9/3/02-0208_article#r2)

[National Research Council, Division on Earth and Life Studies, Commission on Geosciences, Environment and Resources, Board on Atmospheric Sciences and Climate, Committee on Climate, Ecosystems, Infectious Diseases, and Human Health
National Academies Press, May 29, 2001 - Science - 160 pages](https://books.google.com/books?id=ONO42zYIEn0C&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

CFSPH Technical Fact Sheets, Giardiasis at http://www.cfsph.iastate.edu/DiseaseInfo/default.htm

---

**We also have two other close etymological cousins:**

> Zoonoses (Greek “zoon” = animal) are diseases transmissible from
>   living animals to humans.

---

> Sapronoses (Greek “sapros” = decaying; “sapron” means in ecology a
>   decaying organic substrate) are human diseases transmissible from
>   abiotic environment (soil, water, decaying plants, or animal corpses,
>   excreta, and other substrata)

Comment: Such diseases are **anthroponotic** - mention that. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Anthroponotic_disease

Comment: This is not quite correct if NVZ’s link is anything to go by. Just like zoonotic diseases originate in animals (and spread anywhere from there, including to humans), so anthroponotic diseases _originate_ in humans, but can spread to anywhere, including other species of animals. If Nicole’s phrasing is to be taken literally, she is looking for a word for a disease that is only spread directly between humans, neither to nor from other species of animals. (I’m not aware of such a word, but I wasn’t aware of ‘anthroponotic’, either.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquetis Regarding the link you mentioned from NVZ, although a good recommendation, it's not quite as meticulous or comprehensive as the CDC link I gave. Read a few paragraphs down on the CDC link: "It can also be defined as a human-to-human [only] infection with *no animal vector*.[2]"

Comment: It's good form to cite the source (in addition to linking to it).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My link (beautified Wikipedia) actually says the same thing Kace36's does, "It can also be defined as a human-to-human infection with no animal vector."

Comment: @Kace36 The trouble is that “also”, at least if the question is intended to be as restrictive as what I ascribed to it (which I admit is only my interpretation—it's not quite clear). If that reading is correct, then Nicole is looking specifically for a word that spreads from human to human _and cannot spread to other animals_. Anthroponoses do not necessarily entail an animal vector, but do not exclude them either.

Comment: @NVZ Yep, you are right it was on your page too. Do you want to know something so strange? That quote has been edited off the CDC page I linked. That was a letter to an editor from 2003!? Wow. Doesn't matter, I have the link to the original book source which references it. I will update my post. No offense to Janus but I do think it's being slightly fastidious. I will update my post and explain why and how. And link you to a source which will explain the reasons. I hope it will be sufficient. I will also properly cite per Lawrence's post (some will be self evident).

Comment: Thanks, kace36! Regardless of the nuances Janus pointed out, I'd say this works well enough for what I'm looking for. Juxtaposed with _zoonosis_, I think it'll be clear that one category is animal<->human and another is human<->human.

Answer (score -1):

Such a disease is contagious; this is a word which is readily understood by most people and implies contact.

Comment: As I said in my question, "contagious disease" includes zoonotic diseases, and I'm specifically looking for a term that excludes them.